# Should I create a new file for the new RSA key or just append the new RSA key without overwriting the old one ?

Tags: encryption, ssh

I am in this situation (Please note that I am still new to the idea of this ssh thing):

Basically, I have already set up SSH for my Github, so every time I do `git push origin master`, it will not prompt me to enter username and password, which is good. Now I want to set up another SSH for logging onto my school server. I wanted to follow the same instruction which I did for Github in this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/). But after I typed in ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "me@school.com" . It says that `/.ssh/id_rsa already exists. Overwrite (y/n)?` .

Obviously, I do not want to overwrite it, since I still want instant access to my Github account. I know that I can create another `id_rsa` under a different name, but **is this a good approach ? Does it have any side-effects ?** It seems to look nicer if I can just  append the new RSA key to the existing `id_rsa` **but I have no idea how to do so.** (Need to know the right command to do this I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new key. you can us the same **public** key and put it on your school account. The parameter `-C` just put's a comment to your key and it is only there, so that you can easily recognize it as your key. It has nothing to do with the ability log in on a specific server.

Comment: so in my example, ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "me@school.com", "me@school.com" is actually a comment, not the login credentials ? So I can still ssh to school server even though the authorized keys on school server contains the pattern "me@gmail.com" instead of "me@school.com" . Am I correct ?

Comment: correct. you can even edit a copy of id_rsa.pub and exchange  "me@gmail.com" with  "me@gmail.com" before you append the content of this file to `~/.ssh/autherized_keys` on the schools server. But be carefull while editing. Don't edit on a windows system because of the different line end charactes used on windows and linux/osx.

Comment: I realize there is a problem with creating second rsa key under a different filename, which is every time I turn off my laptop and turn it on again I have to do ssh-add new_rsa to insert the new rsa key into the keychain. This is tedious and inefficient .